# C timing memory access for side-channel attacks

Tags: c, pointers, caching, cryptography

I'm taking a cryptography course and I have to do a presentation on side-channel attacks. As such, I'm trying to implement one myself.

I'm specifically trying to follow [this paper](http://eprint.iacr.org/2013/448.pdf). However, I'm having some problems with such a low-level programming.

I wrote a short C program to time the access to a variable, in order to find out whether it's been accessed or not (although in this case I'm the one accessing it, so I know the answer before-hand). The point is then to generalize it to know when some other process reaches some specific state.

Basically, it runs through 10k iterations, and in each iteration with probability 1/10, a pointer is accessed. In every iteration, the time the processor takes to access the pointer is registered, and then the pointer is flushed out of the cache. These values are printed to a file.

Here is the code I wrote (the assembly part is actually from the paper I cited):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>

int probe(char *adrs) {
    volatile unsigned long time;

    asm __volatile__ (
            " mfence \n"
            " lfence \n"
            " rdtsc \n"
            " lfence \n"
            " movl %%eax, %%esi \n"
            " movl (%1), %%eax \n"
            " lfence \n"
            " rdtsc \n"
            " subl %%esi, %%eax \n"
            " clflush 0(%1) \n"
            : "=a" (time)
            : "c" (adrs)
            : "%esi", "%edx");
    return time;
}

void myfunc(void* buffer[]) {
    int nptrs;

    nptrs = backtrace(buffer, 10);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    srand(time(NULL));

    int r = rand(), i;
    struct timespec tim, tim2;
    tim.tv_sec = 0;
    tim.tv_nsec = 5000L;
    void* buffer[10];
    char letter = 'c';
    char* p = &letter;

    FILE *f = fopen("output.txt","w");
    if(f == NULL) printf("Error opening file!\n");

    myfunc(buffer);
    for(i=0; i < 10000; i++) {
        r = rand();
        nanosleep(&tim,&tim2);
        if(r%10 == 3) { // 3 is completely arbitrary; could be any value really
            myfunc(buffer);
            printf("%c ",letter);
        }
        fprintf(f,"%d,%d,%d\n", r%10 == 3, probe(buffer[0]),probe(p)); // print the timings to file, and whether the variable was accessed or not
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And now my problem: this is supposed to write to a file "1,x,y" with small x and y if r % 10 == 3, and "0,x,y" with big x and y otherwise. I've tried to run this in two different VMs running Debian (32 and 64 bits), compiled with gcc 4.7.2 (only flag used was -g) in both, and I get different results, none of which are what I want.

In the 32 bit VM the "probe(buffer[0])" seems to kind of work, although not always. But the "probe(p)" always returns low values (which gives me absolutely no information). Here is a relevant segment of the output (full output available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0uf3e5z6vfu4lxn/output32min.txt)):

```
0,250,48
1,33,54
0,74,33
1,36,33
0,61,33
0,92,33
0,48,62
0,405,33
```

In the 64 bit VM, both values are pretty much always above 4000, independently of the pointers being accessed or not. Another relevant segment (and full output [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3kx3y7twnkziao2/output64min.txt)):

```
1,4341,4371
0,4320,4341
0,4495,4320
```

So my questions are:

- in the 32 bits VM, why is the char* always very fast to access? (Are void* different from char*? Or is it some other reason)
- why do the VMs have different results?
- in the 64 bits VM, why are both values around 4000?

Comment: Someone really loves fencing!

Comment: Took me some time to understand what you meant, I thought you meant the sport :). Yes, according to the authors their purpose is to ensure the instructions are executed in order. I've never really learned asm, but the explanation does seem make sense. :)

Comment: Hm... memory ordering is a *very* subtle topic, and I strongly recommend that you at least skim the architecture manual and get some idea of what each instruction is for. I think half of the fences have exactly zero effect, but I couldn't guarantee it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty interesting question.

There shouldn't be a difference between char* and void*, the only difference would be in the pointer arithmetic.  However I think that the difference you see in the times from 32-bit to 64-bit is due to the architecture changes.  64-bit is generally slower at accessing memory than 32-bit, but since there are more registers they normally don't have to access memory as much.  [Here's a link to info on 64-bit architecture, and the difference from 32-bit.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7034/what-are-the-differences-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-and-which-should-i-choose)